# Finding a min value for each key causing efficiency issues

Tags: sql, performance, hadoop, mapreduce, hive

I have a very large table, CLAIMS, with the following columns:

```
p_key
c_key
claim_type
```

Each row is uniquely defined by p_key, c_key. Often there will be multiple c_keys for each p_key. The table would look like this:

```
p_key  c_key  claim_type
1      1      A
1      2      A
2      3      B
2      5      C
3      1      B
```

I want to find the minimum c_key for each p_key. This is my query:

```
SELECT p_key, 
min(c_key) as min_ckey
from CLAIMS
GROUP BY p_key
```

The issue is, when I run this as a mapreduce job through HIVE CLI (0.13), the reduce portion takes 30 minutes to even get 5% done. I'm not entirely sure what could cause a simple query to take so long. This query gives the same issue:

```
SELECT p_key, 
row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY p_key ORDER BY c_key) as RowNum
from CLAIMS
```

So my question is why would the reduce portion of a seemingly simple mapreduce job take so long? Any suggestions on how to investigate this/improve the query would also be appreciated.

Comment: are p_key and c_key marked as primary key?

Comment: My best guess is that the only one reducer is being used for the job.  I don't know why that would be, on this query.

Comment: @GordonLinoff its using some 800 reducers

Answer (score 1):

Do you know if the data is imbalanced? If there is one `p_key` with a very large number of `c_key` values compared to the average case, then the reducer which deals with that p_key will take a very long time.

Alternatively, is it possible that there are a small number of `p_key` values in general? Since you're grouping by `p_key` that would limit the number of reducers doing useful work.

Answer (score 1):

The reduce phase occurs in three stages. When <=33% is shuffle, between 33% and 66% is sort, and >= 67% is the reduce phase.

Your job sounds like it is getting hung up in the shuffle portion of the reduce phase.  My guess is that your data is spread all over and this portion is IO bound.  Your observations are being moved to reducers.

You can try bucketing your data:

```
create table claim_bucket (p_key string, c_key string, claim_type string) 
 clustered by (p_key) into 6 buckets 
 row format delimited fields terminated by ",";
```

You may want more or less buckets and this will require some heavy lifting by hive inititally but should speed up subsequent queries of the table where p_key is used.

Of course you haven't left much else to go on here.  If you post an edit and give more information you might get a better answer.  Good luck.

Comment: additionally try looking at this https://streever.atlassian.net/wiki/display/HADOOP/Hive+Performance+Tips